# git rm 後に git status で表示されるメッセージの意味が分からない

Tags: git

gitのコマンド操作で以下のように記述しました。
要するにgit rmコマンドでfileB.txtというファイルを削除したということです。
git rmコマンドを打った後にgit statusで確認すると"deleted: fileB.txt"をコミットしてくれというようなメッセージが出ます。

これは「fileB.txtを削除したことをgitに記録として残しておけ」ということなのでしょうか？

`git rm --cached fileB.txt` と打ちgit statusで確認すると
同じくdeleted: fileB.txt をコミットしろというメッセージと
fileB.txtをgit add コマンドでステージングするように促されます。

初心者で少し理解しにくい部分です。わかる方いらっしゃいましたら簡潔に教えて下さい。よろしくお願いいたします。

```
git_practice ±|master|→ ls -a
.  ..  .git  .gitignore  fileA.txt  fileB.txt  secirity.gif

git_practice ±|master|→ git rm fileB.txt
rm 'fileB.txt'

git_practice ±|master ✗|→ ls
fileA.txt  secirity.gif

git_practice ±|master ✗|→ git ls-files
.gitignore
fileA.txt
secirity.gif

git_practice ±|master ✗|→ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        deleted:    fileB.txt
```

Comment: ファイルを新たに追加した場合や、ファイルの中身を書き換えた場合のコミットまでの手順は理解できていますか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> これは「fileB.txtを削除したことをgitに記録として残しておけ」ということなのでしょうか？

はい、`deleted: fileB.txt` というのは「`fileB.txt` が削除された」という情報が stage されているという意味で、あとは `git commit` すればコミット履歴にファイル削除の情報が追加されます。